# how do I set error on the button like the error of edittext?

Tags: java, android, xml

There is a button for picking time using `timepickerdialog`. I want to set the `error` when time is *not* selected. I tried these codes below. The error occurs but after picking time, it still appears. I need help

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(btnDate.getText().toString())) {    
    btnDate.setError("Bu alan boş olamaz");
    btnDate.requestFocus();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should not set error in button, rather you should set error on control which needs to be filled up

Comment: When you retrieve text from you textBoc you retrieve string. Now you just have to check if you have empty string

Comment: regarding to your previous question as well as this, it seems like you are following the same pattern :D. If i may suggest can you use toast message or snackbar to display error? It is a better practice in general.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_prompt_icon"` and put come prompt error to show he is missing some in order to process.

**OR**

Programatically you add this error icon in button on your error condition.

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_prompt_icon);
txtVw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, null, img);
```

- If you using `setError()` in order to remove error when user choose correct option than make `btnDate.setError (null);` as by doing this it will disappear this error.
- You may use `Toast` or `Snackbar` for showing errors & suggestions in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, please:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(btnDate.getText().toString())) {
        btnDate.setError("Bu alan boş olamaz");
        btnDate.requestFocus();
} else {
        btnDate.setError("")
        // Some actions what you need
 }
```